# Update values in json (array elements) using jq in loop

Tags: json, jq

I have a input json file with an array. I need to updated two values (ver & date) in each array element. I could come up with below script but need help. I have hardcoded the ver & date to simplify the script.

input.json

```
[
  {
    "svcname": "svc1",
    "repo": "https://repo.mycom.org/repocontext/svc1-list",
    "ver": "0.1",
    "date": "2019-11-05"
  },
  {
    "svcname": "svc1",
    "repo": "https://repo.mycom.org/repocontext/svc1-list",
    "ver": "0.1",
    "date": "2019-12-21"
  }
]
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x
injson=input.json
updatedjson=$(jq .[] ${injson})

services=$(cat ${injson} | jq '.[] | .svcname' | tr -d \")
i=1
for svc in $services; do 

        echo "==>$svc"
        echo "======> input json=${updatedjson}"
        echo "======> update ver=${i}"
        updatedjson=$(echo ${updatedjson} | jq ". | select( .name ==\"$svc\").ver=\"$i\"" | jq . )
        svcdate="2020-01-$i"
        echo "======> update date=$svcdate"
        updatedjson=$(echo ${updatedjson} | jq ". | select( .name ==\"$svc\").date=\"$svcdate\"" | jq . )
        echo "============================================"
        echo
        i=`expr $i + 1`

done

echo "======= write to file ====="
echo ${updatedjson}
echo ${updatedjson} | jq . > outjson.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the true features of `jq`. What you shown in a loop, iterating over all the JSON objects can be simply reduced to one `reduce()` construct that is sort of a `for` loop in `jq` given an initial value and runs the filter incrementally

```
jq 'reduce range(0, length) as $d (.; (.[$d].ver = ($d+1|tostring)) | (.[$d].date = "2020-01-\($d+1)")) '
```

A brief explanation of how it works

1. The range expression returns a list with numbers generated from 0 to upto the length of the objects in the array. For your given input it produces `0,1` which is assigned to `d`
2. The `reduce` expression given the input value `.` the whole JSON, runs by setting the values in each object indexed by `$d`. So `.[$d].ver` refers to the `ver` field in the zeroth index. This is done incrementally till all the objects are processed.
3. The same way the date field is modified using `[$d].date` with the value string prefixed (YYYY-MM-) and date is set accordingly.

Comment: Now I am trying to use actual variables (in place of hardcoded values) but running into jq sytax error.  === echo ${updatedjson} | jq "reduce range(0, length) as  (.; (. | .[] | select( .name ==\"$svc\").version=\"$ver\") | (. | .[] | select( .name ==\"$svc\").date=\"$svcdate\")) " ====    & error is: ==== jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '$' or '[' or '{' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: ======

Comment: Thanks a lot @Inian, I learn a lot from your code